# get_post_meta producing white screen of death

Tags: post-meta

I’m using Divi, and added the following code below the post content in `single.php`:

```
<?php if(get_post_meta($post->ID, 'store-url', true) !== '') { ?>
    <div class="store"><a href="<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'store-url', true); ?>">Purchase a digital copy from $4 here. Up to 5184 x 3456 pixels in size</a>.</div>
<?php } ?>
```

I have a single custom field of name `store-url` with a value of a URL.

When I view a single post, I receive a 500 internal server error.

This is the default content plus the custom code (`#purchase`):

```
<div class="entry-content">
<?php
    do_action( 'et_before_content' );

    the_content();

    wp_link_pages( array( 'before' => '<div class="page-links">' . esc_html__( 'Pages:', 'Divi' ), 'after' => '</div>' ) );
?>
</div> <!-- .entry-content -->
<div id="purchase">
    <?php if(get_post_meta($post->ID, 'store-url', true) !== '') { ?>
    <div class="store"><a href="<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'store-url', true); ?>">Purchase a digital copy from $4 here. Up to 5184 x 3456 pixels in size</a>.</div>
    <?php } ?>
</div>
```

Debug log displays:

> PHP Notice:  wpdb::escape is **deprecated** since version
>   3.6.0! Use wpdb::prepare() or esc_sql() instead. in /home/doigc349/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 3838

Help appreciated.

Regards,
Steve

Comment: There should be something else in debug log, it's just notice. Notice won't cause white screen or 500 internal server error. Try dumping $post, that's probably causing the fatal error.

Comment: Thanks @sven. There was `PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'endif' (T_ENDIF), expecting end of file` (now fixed) & `PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function et_builder_is_product_tour_enabled()` (now fixed too). Post loads now.

Answer (score 3):

You have to add this line to the top of `single.php`

```
global $post;
```

or, use `get_the_ID()`, as Divi does in the same `single.php`

```
if( get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'store-url', true) !== '') {...
```